# "This operation returned because the timeout period expired" appears when trying to open Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Windows machine, but whenever I click on it to open it, I get "This operation returned because the timeout period expired". How can I solve the problem?
[image]

before installing I enabled windows virtual machine then i restarted. afterwards i turned on "windows subsystem for linux" in windows features, then i restarted my computer. I followed [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), because my store app doesn't work well. I didn't do any boot after installing ubuntu 18.04. i used powershell to install it, it said the operation was successful but when i click on ubuntu i am getting that error above. so i restarted my computer but it didn't help.

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue?